# c++ atomic read/write misunderstanding

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Why program with this code sometimes prints "2" ?

```
int main() {
    std::atomic<int> a;
    a = 0;

    std::thread t1([&]{++a;});
    std::thread t2([&]{a++;});
    std::thread t3([&]{
        a = a.load() + 1;
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    if (a != 3) {
        std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've thought `std::atomic` guarantees that all operations will be done atomically so writing here(incrementing) will use a memory barrier and we will have always `3` at the end of threads work. I've explored the code and found out that the problem thread is `t3` but I can't understand why it is wrong.

Comment: `a = a.load() + 1` isn't just one operation though.

Comment: ++a and a++ is not done atomically. you might want to have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add

Comment: @Rush What about this then? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith
@JonathanPotter I've thought so but how does increment work then? I think it needs one read at least too, is not it? So in `t3` I've tried to simulate it but it seems it is wrong as @ParkYoung-Bae said. So I think the problem is that `t3` overwrites with an old value.

Comment: @Rush: `a` is not an `int`, it is an `atomic<int>`: you appear to be citing wisdom for a scenario different from that of this post.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`t3`, unlike the two other threads, does not perform an atomic add. Instead, it atomically loads `a`, performs the arithmetic (add 1) *on a temporary*, and atomically stores that new value back to `a`. This overwrites `a` regardless of atomic operations that might have happened in between.

So you can have the following scenario:

1. `t1` or `t2` atomically increment `a` which is now equal to 1.
2. `t3` atomically loads 1.
3. `t1` or `t2` atomically increment `a` which is now equal to 2.
4. `t3` performs a non-atomic add on the previously loaded value and atomically stores back 2.